# How do I provide a generic function as a type parameter?

Tags: generics, rust

In [chapter 13](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#storing-closures-using-generic-parameters-and-the-fn-traits) of *The Rust Programming Language*, there is task to implement a `Cacher` struct that will cache a generic function. For a concrete function this works:

```
struct Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<u32>,
}
```

I can't figure out how to make it work for a generic function. If I do something like:

```
struct Cacher<T, A, R>
where
    T: Fn(A) -> R,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<R>,
}
```

The compiler complains with:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `A` is never used
 --> src/lib.rs:2:18
  |
2 | struct Cacher<T, A, R>
  |                  ^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `A`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`
```

How can I let the compiler know that I want `T` to be generic function?

Comment: Have you considered including a [PhantomData](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) field in your struct, like the compiler suggests?

Comment: Well, `struct Casher<T, A, R>
where
    T: Fn(A) -> R,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: Option<R>,
    a: PhantomData<A>,
}` works.

Comment: Yell, you don't want the closure to have any parameter, because how would your cacher call it otherwise? Just remove `A`.

Comment: If I remove `A` compiler complains that inside `where` clause I get `A` from thin air.

Comment: as far as I understand `PhantomData` needed eliminated unbounded lifetimes in struct definition. But if I will create this struct with `PhantomData` field what value should I assign to it? Let's say I want to implement `new`:


    impl<T, A, R> Cacher<T, A, R>
    where T: Fn(A) -> R
    {
        fn new(calculation: T) -> NaiveCacher<T, A, R> {
            Cacher { calculation, value: None}
        }
    }

this won't work because I need value for `a

Comment: As an alternative, you might be able to use a function pointer (if you don't close over any state). I.e., `calculation: fn(A) -> R` (note the lower case `fn`), and omit `T`). But I believe using `Fn` is preferred to be more flexible in what you can accept.